# Переменная не хочет приобретать значение выделенного элемента

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

```
    var currentElement = null
var mDown = (e) => {
    //console.log("кнопка нажата")
    currentElement = e.traget
    console.log(e.target) // корректно отображает элемент куда нажал кнопку
    console.log(currentElement)// undefined
    } 
document.addEventListener('mousedown' , mDown);
```

Пытаюсь реализовать простую дарг-н-дроп функцию на сайте. по непонятным причинам переменная currentElement не хочет принимать значение e.target. С чем это связано и как быть?

Comment: даже если добавить в функцию var Newone = e.target console.log(Newone) отображает правильно. но с переменной за пределами функции не работает

Comment: Вы уверены, что переменная currentElement определяется на том же уровне, что и mDown?

Comment: да. Все точно так как написано в коде

Comment: У вас опечатка: e.tRAget вместо e.target.